# AngularJs Nvd3 Charts

Tags: angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

Hi Community,
            I am struck with this for few past days..I tried the nvd3 master in github.Then I played with the LinePlusBarFocusChart.I have one Issue,In the example,they had used the numeric values..for Data Load

var testdata = [
  {
    "key" : "Quantity" ,
     "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [  "EGG" , 121000.0] , [ 1138683600000 , 127000.0] ]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price" ,
    "values" : [ [  "EGG" , 71.89] , [ 1138683600000 , 75.51]  ]
  }
]

while I change the First value as a String..My chart Looks like this,

can anyone help me to finish this Issue....Reply will be appreciated.

Regards,
Yuvaraj...

Answer (score 0):

Each data element is a series sequential element, so you need have a time variable. But you can add an additional variable with labels to the dataset

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        "key" : "Quantity" ,
        "bar": true,
        "values" : [ 
            [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0, 'EGG1'] , 
            [ 1138683600000 , 1271000.0, 'EGG2'] , 
            ...
        ]
    },{
        "key" : "Price" ,
        "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 71.89], ... ]
    }
].map(function(series) {
    series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { 
        return {x: d[0], y: d[1], label: d[2] } 
    });
    return series;
});
```

and then manipulate it with `xAxis.tickFormat` chart option. This option can be defined as a function like:

```
xAxis: {
    tickFormat: function(d) {
        var dx = $scope.data[0].values[d].x;
        var label = $scope.data[0].values[d].label;
        return label ? label : d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx));
    }        
}
```

See [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QiBdW7?p=preview). (It uses [this](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/) directive here.)

Comment: I have a dataset with string values not a single String "EGG".                             var testdata = [
  {
    "key" : "Quantity" ,
  "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [  'EGG' , 121000.0] , [ 1138683600000 , 127000.0] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price" ,
 "values" : [ [  'EGG' , 71.89] , [ 1138683600000 , 75.51],[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89] ,[  "EGG" , 71.89]  ]
  }
]  can you show some examples..

Comment: keep your time variable and add another with labels. I've updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for you reply krispo..I have one doubt in ur code,EGG2,EGG3 values are not showing in label..can you check plz.

Comment: because dataset is large - just zoom the chart.

Comment: Oh,Thanks Krispo,Works Fine.I have One Query,I need to pass Three parameters ah..I think like passing"values" : [ [  'EGG' , 121000.0] , ,[  "EGG2" , 71.89] ] to load the chart.It is not possible ah..I have to pass the Date,value and label ah..